# How to get iterator index/key using protractor + angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Is there a way to access the iterator index/key when looking for elements by repeater?

```
protractor.By.repeater("(id,cat) in pets")
```

In this case I'm looking to get access to "id" of the cat. The "id" is NOT one of the columns displayed as a value in the table, it is used for navigation as `ng-click="goto('/pets/'+cat.id)"`. There is no binding in the HTML such as `{{id}}` or `{{cat.id}}` so doing the following:

```
ptor.findElements(protractor.By.repeater("(id,cat) in pets").column('cat.id'))
```

returns an empty element: `[]`

I've also, unsuccessfully,  tried doing something like:

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.repeater("(id,cat) in pets").row(0).column('cat.id'))
```

What is the correct way to access that specific index?

**Here's the non-shortened syntax of the answer by Jmr:**

```
ptor.findElements(protractor.By.repeater('(id, cat) in pets')).then(function (arr) {
    arr[0].evaluate('cat.id').then(function (id) {
        console.log(id);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking to evaluate something that's not on the page, so the 'row' and 'column' methods won't work. If you just use the repeater, you will get an array of all of the rows. You can then use the `evaluate` command to evaluate Angular expressions in the context of that element. For example (using shortened syntax),

```
element.all(by.repeater('(id, cat) in pets')).then(function(arr) {
  arr[0].evaluate('cat.id'); // This is a promise which resolves to the id.
});
```

Comment: terrific, that's exactly what I was looking for.