# Click on column in table - Protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have pretty big compelx TABLE in HTML, and I need click first row:

```
<div class="ui-grid-canvas"> //this is whole table
 <div ng-repeat="(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index" class="ui-grid-row ng-scope" ng-style="containerCtrl.rowStyle(rowRenderIndex)" ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}" style="margin-top: 0px;"> //this is one line
   <div ui-grid-row="row" row-render-index="rowRenderIndex" class="ng-isolate-scope"> //this is blanked part (740x0px)
    <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-col0 ui-grid-row-header-cell" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
     <div class="ui-grid-disable-selection ng-scope"> //stil first column
      <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"> //stil first column
       <div class="ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons ui-grid-icon-ok ng-scope" ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}" ng-click="selectButtonClick(row, $event)">&nbsp;</div> //clickable part of first element.
```

As it looks like this I need to click on row number 20, 21,22  is here somebody who can help me with that?

I try with something like:

```
element(by.css('.ui-grid-canvas').row(22)).element(by.css('[ng-click="selectButtonClick(row, $event)"]')).click();
```

but i get error:

```
r(".ui-grid-canvas") has no method 'row'
```

Please is here somebody who can help me with this?

EDIT:
screen of code:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`element.all()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) with [`by.repeater()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater):

```
element.all(by.repeater('(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows')).then(function(arr) {
  arr[20].all(by.css('[ng-click^=selectButtonClick]')).first().click();
});
```

You may also need to *scroll to the element* before making a click:

```
var scrollIntoView = function () {
    arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
}

element.all(by.repeater('(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows')).then(function(arr) {
    var row = arr[20];
    browser.executeScript(scrollIntoView, row.getWebElement()).then(function () {
        row.all(by.css('[ng-click^=selectButtonClick]')).first().click();
    });
});
```

See also:

- [How to get iterator index/key using protractor + angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154148/how-to-get-iterator-index-key-using-protractor-angular)

Comment: Hey alecxe, I really appreciate that you trying to help :) It's pretty hard to find anything for protractor. 
Anyway I try to follow your advise it throw me error back:
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("[ng-click=\"selectButtonClick(row, $event)\"]")

Comment: @Andurit okay, but are you sure every repeating section has this clickable `div` with the `ng-click` value `selectButtonClick(row, $event)`?

Comment: This will prolly looks really lame but I'm not sure how to test it.

Comment: Dear alecxe thank you for that fast response, it's really cool to see somebody care so much about my problem.

Your last code throw this error:
     TypeError: Object function (subLocator) {
  return this.all(subLocator).toElementFinder_();
} has no method 'all'

Comment: Error: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By.cssSelector("[ng-c
lick^=selectButtonClick]")

Comment: @Andurit okay, let's try to rely on the class instead: `arr[20].all(by.css('.ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons')).first().click();`

Comment: Oh, @alecxe Same error as well :(, btw edited my question ....adding there screen of code

Comment: @Andurit could you try to change the index and see if the error would be reproduceable on any index (e.g. use `1` instead of `20` etc.)?

Comment: Okey I tryed it with inxe 1 and index 2 and it works, after that i try index 11 and it didn't work. I'm thinking it can be because that part is scrollable. So user don't see index 20 at start, is there a way how we can fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72066/discussion-between-andurit-and-alecxe).

Comment: How to return this element instead of click here